# A holomorphic function on a punctured disc has removable singularity iff it can be approximated by polynomials on a circle

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $r>0$ and $f: D(0,2r)\setminus\{0\} \to \mathbb{C}$ be
>   holomorphic, where $D(0,2r):= \{z \in \mathbb{C} \,:\, |z|<2r\}$. Show
>   that f has removable singularity at $0$ iff $$\inf_{p\in\mathbb{C}[z]} \left( \sup_{|z|=r} |p(z)-f(z)| \right)= 0.$$

The one direction seems straightforward: If $f$ has removable singularity then consider the partial sums of the Taylor series of $f$ which converge unifomrly to $f$ on $\overline{D(0,r)}$.

What about the converse? There is a sequence $(p_n)$ of polynomials such that $ \displaystyle \sup_{|z|=r} |p_n(z)-f(z)| < 1/n$, and if I'm not wrong this implies that $\int_{|z|=r} f(z) \, dz  = 0$, but I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: Consider $z \mapsto z^k\cdot f(z)$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the Laurent series of $f$$$f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_nz^n.$$As you say, we have $\int_{|z|=r}f(z)dz=0$, and this implies that $a_{-1}=0$. Now let $k$ be some positive integer. As Daniel suggests, consider the function $z\mapsto z^k f(z)$. Its Laurent series is$$z^k f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_nz^{k+n}.$$Since this function can also be approximated by polynomials, we deduce $\int_{|z|=r}z^kf(z)dz=0$. Consequently, $a_{-1-k}=0$. Hence, the Laurent series of $f$ has only non-negative powers of $z$.